# Prevent inspect element from targeting element?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Is there a way to force inspect element via Chrome to ignore a certain element?

I've often had a need to put an overlay over the entire site (say for development purposes) and the only problem is my development workflow suffering due to "inspect element" always targeting that top level element.

I guess another way to ask this question is, how do I place an overlay (site PSD) over a live site, without it affecting my inspector workflow?

Thanks for any suggestions!

I just tried `:before`, which allows text selection / doesn't appear in the inspector, but it's still caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was just looking at my old answers, and not sure if it's just new chrome behavior or what, but Chrome's inspect element respects `pointer-events: none;`

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're talking about using the right-click option to inspect element or the magnify glass to select an object on the page.  I don't think there is a way to prevent it from working that way without a little work on  your part.

You could have a button that turns on and off that overlay locally for you (or a JS snippet that you can run in the console to delete the overlay).

You could select the overlay and then in the inspect element portion of the tools right-click the object and delete the node (as long as it isn't the parent of all the other content).  Then you can select the object on the page.

Or you can just inspect the element (the top one) and then drill down in the DOM tree in the inspect element tab of Chrome to your element.  One nice thing though, if you do it this way when you refresh it should take you back to that element in the inspect element tab (unless it's really complex with iFrames loading on the page, in which case it won't do that).